# XNA - no definition for 'isMouseVisible'

Tags: c#, xna

I'm trying to get my cursor visible in an XNA game using isMouseVisible, but it doesn't want to work. The error:

> 'StopWatch.Game1' does not contain a definition for 'isMouseVisible' and no extension method 'isMouseVisible' accepting a first argument of type 'StopWatch.Game1' could be found

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace StopWatch
{
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        public SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        public static Game1 Instance;
        StopWatch stopWatch;

        public Game1()
        {
            this.isMouseVisible = true;
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Instance = this;
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 512;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 512;
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            stopWatch = new StopWatch(); 
            base.Initialize();
        }

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            stopWatch.LoadContent();
        }

        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            stopWatch.UnloadContent();
        }

        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            stopWatch.Update(gameTime);
            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            stopWatch.Draw(gameTime);
            spriteBatch.End();
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IsMouseVisible = true`

Capitalize the I

Remember, Using intelisence you can view methods and variables just by typing the beginning.

Comment: Thats why I use an RSS Feed :P

Comment: I know what you mean, I hate when I spend Half and hour trying to do something, take a break... come back and be like "Oh duh.."